# Which democratic countries / states don't recognise Israel de facto or de jure (the Economist democracy Index)?

Tags: international-relations, israel, democracy, religion, indicators

Re the [right of Israel](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Legitimacy_of_the_State_of_Israel) to [exist](https://qr.ae/pKfnrq) as a [Jewish nation](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=DyULayL5KaU), what are the countries that deny Israel either [de facto or de jure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_recognition_of_Israel#List_by_country) and are democracies, defined by being [at least 6.00+ on the economist democracy index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Economist_Democracy_Index#List_by_country)?

I can't really find a list elsewhere other than manually checking Wikipedia, so I'm just posting an answer based on what I checked on Wikipedia.

**Question:** But anyway, where could I have found some list that shows this s.t. I didn't need to reinvent the wheel, assuming I'm correct? And if I'm incorrect, then please point out why by either showing such a list or manually double checking my answer. If you show a list, then feel free to use an alternative definition of democracy, hopefully based on a measure/[indicator](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/6104/what-is-the-meaning-purpose-of-the-indicators-tag).

Comment: The [tag:indicators] was previously discussed [on Meta](https://politics.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6104/26455)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

I can't really find a list elsewhere other than manually checking Wikipedia, so here's the result of manually checking Wikipedia.

Here are the ones that don't recognise Israel [either de facto or de jure](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/International_recognition_of_Israel#List_by_country):

[image]

[image]

[image]

Manually (so I could be wrong!) checking each on [economist democracy index](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Economist_Democracy_Index#List_by_country) gives just 4:

1. Indonesia - both
2. Jamaica - de jure rejection but de facto acceptance
3. Malaysia - both
4. Trinidad and Tobago - de jure rejection but de facto acceptance

Notes:

1. The only 2 democracies that de facto reject Israel are Indonesia & Malaysia. [Both](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Muslim_supporters_of_Israel) are Muslim majority countries.
2. T.E.D. points out TEDI says all 4 are flawed not full. And you might say 'Aha, they're not "real" democracies!' But then again Israel & US are flawed too. So, well, so much for that.

Comment: Having text rather than images would be far better

Comment: If text is hard, a link to the relevant Wikipedia page would help. (I get that it's in the question, but it's hard to find.)

Comment: Technically, all 4 are classified as "flawed democracies" rather than "full democracies". For comparison's sake, so is the USA.

Comment: @T.E.D. what reference are you using for that classification? Which categorisation system/scale are you referencing?

Comment: @ChrisHalcrow - The latest Economist Democracy index, just like the answer said.

Comment: @wizzwizz4 ok done. thanks.

Comment: @D.BenKnoble Well the main point was for someone to actually give a better answer. Had I done that it and then someone did then that's more wheel invention right?